# Android Manifest application:supportsRtl

Tags: android, localization, android-manifest

I write a testcase with robotium but I face a problem that is : how to check in AndroidManifest.xml 
1- if the attribute "supportsRtl" is already exist

2- if its value is true

```
<application
android:name=".MApplication"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Main"
android:supportsRtl="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Robotium actually, but you can Try the following:

```
Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
boolean isRTL = config.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
```